# Trouble compiling ncurses-st-menu for BSD

Tags: freebsd, bsd, openbsd, netbsd, dragonfly-bsd

I found a package on github (https://github.com/okbob/ncurses-st-menu) and am having trouble compile it for BSD platforms like NetBSD or OpenBSD. The instructions say to do ./autogen.sh, ./configure, and then make. So I install the autoconf, autotools, libtool, gettext, and any other necessary packages and run ./autogen.sh. It works without spitting out any errors. But ./configure says it doesn't support "OS x86_64-unknown-netbsd9.0" if for example on NetBSD. Can someone else try to compile this program? Because if this was done by autotools, it certainly should support any of the four major BSD operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I created a port for FreeBSD [here](https://github.com/swills/ncurses-st-menu-freebsd-port/tree/master/devel/ncurses-st-menu), maybe it will help you get it running on NetBSD. The most important part is the removal of the `AC_MSG_ERROR(["OS $host_os is not supported"])` line from `tools/ax_pdcurses.m4`, then touching `config.make`, calling `autogen.sh` to re-generate the `configure` script. It's also important to set `CFLAGS` properly and have the appropriate dependencies installed. Also, I used `gmake` rather than patch the `Makefile` since I didn't feel motivated to fix it completely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the autogen/config tools,
but if you look the configure file:

https://github.com/okbob/ncurses-st-menu/blob/master/configure
lines 4245-4269 only checks for linux,cygwin,mingw.

For other OS gives the error: OS $host_os is not supported